# What should be the clearance and creepage for the line to line 440 Vac and line to neutral 240 Vac of the three-phase system on PCB?

Tags: electrical-engineering, power-electronics, energy, electrical, circuit-design

Also is there any link to calculate this as per the UL and other industrial standards

Comment: Sometimes design is insufficient.  If concerned, require a qc hi-pot test.  Some pcb manufacturers might fail to seal or coat something resulting in different outcomes...